# Why don't the programs implemented by Golang use the functions of libc.so.6, such as socket()?

Tags: linux, go, shared-libraries, system-calls

Thanks for answering my question. I am working for a project recently. In this project, I write a shared library and set the `LD_PRELAOD` to the shared library's path. I want to intercept some programs' system calls by using this shared library, such as `socket(), bind(), send()`. It works for C-programs and Python-programs, but it doesn't work for Golang-programs. Later I know that Go-programs comply with the static libraries.
So I tried this command: `go build -linkshared <test-name>`, unlucky, it failed.
Finally, I use the command `nm` to check the symbols in the application.
And I found these:

```sh
# nm -Do <go-program-name> | grep socket
# results are as follows
<go-program-name>: <address> T net.socket
<go-program-name>: <address> D net.socektFunc
<go-program-name>: <address> T syscall.socket

# nm -Do <C-program-name> | grep socket
<C-program>: U socket
```

And this is the screenshot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osF3C.png)
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why don't the programs implemented by Go[...] use the functions of libc.so.6.

Because Go uses direct syscalls to the underlying OS.